# Is there a function holomorphic on $\{z\in \mathbb{C} :~ \lvert z\rvert<1\}$ and continuous on $S^1$ but not holomorphic on $S^1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Lately I have seen many problems where it was given that the considered function was holomorphic on $\{z\in \mathbb{C} :~ \lvert z\rvert<1 \}$ and continuous on the boundary. Do functions satisfying such a property, but not holomorphic on the closure even exist?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by holomorphic on $S^1$. Usually, "holomorphic on a set $A$" is reserved for *open* $A$.

Comment: $\sum z^{2^n}/2^n$ is clearly continuos on the boundary of unit circle and holomorphic inside, but it is not holomorphic at any boundary point (in the usual sense that there is a holomorphic extension in a neighborhood of it) (why? - think holomorphic implies derivative holomorphic); this clearly can be made $C^m$ on the boundary by putting $2^{n(m+1)}$ in the denominator and with slightly more care we can even make it $C^{\infty}$ and still not holomorphic

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/10831/31729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it extended to a holomorphic function on $S^1$, $f(z)$ would extend to a holomorphic function on $|z| < 1 + \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, which would mean its power series at the origin has radius of convergence at least $1 + \epsilon$. So all you have to do is choose say $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {z^n \over n^2}$ which has radius of convergence $1$ but which is continuous on $|z| \leq 1$, and this function is not holomorphic on $S^1$.